# necesito exportar en excel un NVARCHAR DESDE JAVA

Tags: sql-server, excel, java-ee, datatable, cursor

Estoy usando base de datos sql server en la cual estoy usando un cursor.

Necesito leer este **NVARCHAR** desde java y así poder exportarlo en excel desde java.

Tener en consideracion:
que dichas columnas de mi excel van agregarse mas en un futuro.

formato exportacion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

script tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE TB_INGRESO(
    PERIODO varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    UE varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    SEDE varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    AREA varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRODUCTO varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    FECHA date NOT NULL,
    PRECIO decimal(19, 6) NULL,
    CANTIDAD decimal(19, 6) NULL
    )
    GO

    ALTER TABLE TB_INGRESO
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TB_MSTINGRESOS PRIMARY KEY(PERIODO,UE,SEDE,AREA,PRODUCTO,FECHA)

    GO
```

Procedimiento Almacenado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

metodo java:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado de mi vista (los valores de mes y anio los estoy metiendo en duro en mi bean)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me recomendaría otra forma de obtener dicho reporte en excel

Comment: Sería más útil para quienes deseen reproducir el escenario que en vez de colocar imagenes de código, se coloque el código (seleccionas, presionas Control + K y se da un formato bonito). Saludos

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Usa el [code-snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1547/78) [y las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.